# Is it possible to run pipelines and crawl multiple URL at the same time in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

My spider looks like this

```py
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request
from ProjectName.items import ProjectName

class SpidernameSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spidername'
    allowed_domains = ['webaddress']
    start_urls = ['webaddress/query1']

    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='horizontal css')),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='vertical css'),
                     callback='parse_item')
            )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = ProjectName()
        1_css = 'css1::text'
        item['1'] = response.css(1_css).extract()

        item = ProjectName()
        2_css = 'css2::text'
        item['2'] = response.css(2_css).extract()
        return item
```

and my pipeline like this:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class RemoveIncompletePipeline(object):
    def reminc_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['1']:
            return item
        else:
            raise DropItem("Missing content in %s" % item)
```

Everything works fine, when the value for field 1 is missing then, the coresponding item is taken out from the output.

But, when I change `start_urls`, in order to do the job for multiple queries, like this:

```py
f = open("queries.txt")
start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
f.close()
```

or like this:

```py
start_urls = [i.strip() for i in open('queries.txt').readlines()]
```

Then the output contains the items with missing value for field 1.

What's going on? And how I can avoid that?

For the record `queries.txt` looks like that:

> webaddress/query1
>   webaddress/query2

Comment: @rook, thx for the edit

Comment: Out of interest, are the URLs on the same server/domain? If so, you'll not want to parallelise them, unless you're sure that the hit rate won't get you IP blocked.

Comment: Indeed, they are from the same domain, since it's about inputing queries on a search engine which results are links inside the domain . What would you recommend to avoid being blocked ? I haven't been blocked so far as I didn't retrieve more than 50 items for testing. I'd like to get like 500 000 items, split in 15 to 30 queries.

Comment: That's a very large amount of scraping, and in general I would expect you would get blocked even without parallelisation, assuming that each of those half a million items are individual HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) you should override `start_requests` method.

> This method must return an iterable with the first Requests to crawl
>   for this spider.
>
> This is the method called by Scrapy when the spider is opened for
>   scraping when no particular URLs are specified. If particular URLs are
>   specified, the make_requests_from_url() is used instead to create the
>   Requests. This method is also called only once from Scrapy, so it’s
>   safe to implement it as a generator.

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request
from ProjectName.items import ProjectName

class SpidernameSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spidername'
    allowed_domains = ['webaddress']
    start_urls = ['webaddress/query1']

    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='horizontal css')),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='vertical css'),
                     callback='parse_item')
            )

    def start_requests(self):
        return [scrapy.Request(i.strip(), callback=self.parse_item) for i in open('queries.txt').readlines()]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = ProjectName()
        1_css = 'css1::text'
        item['1'] = response.css(1_css).extract()

        item = ProjectName()
        2_css = 'css2::text'
        item['2'] = response.css(2_css).extract()
        return item
```

UPD:
Just put this code into your spider class

```
def start_requests(self):
    return [scrapy.Request(i.strip(), callback=self.parse_item) for i in open('queries.txt').readlines()]
```

UPD:
Your have a wrong logic in your `parse_item` method. You need to fix it.

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    for job in response.css('div.card-top')
        item = ProjectName()
        # just quick example.
        item['city'] = job.xpath('string(//span[@class="serp-location"])').extract()[0].replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '')
        # TODO: you should fill other item fields
        # ...
        yeild item
```

Comment: Thx a lot, I'll try that. Shall I leave `start_urls = ['webaddress/query1']`?

Comment: Doesn't work, here is the [log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l77o50rao9osqoj/scrapylog.txt?dl=0)

Comment: You have some errors in your `parse_item` method. I corrected the anwser, check it up once more. Make a new question, if you have a problem with selectors. Your log shows what scrapy calls multiple start urls, this question is solved

Comment: The `parse_item` method that I used was taken from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljpir1isp8120bm/%5B2015%5D%C3%82%C2%A0Richard%20Lawson%20-%20Web%20Scraping%20with%20Python.pdf?dl=0). I checked all my selectors with `scrapy shell` and they seem to do the job. Anyway spider works fine, it is just that pipeline's `DropIIem` seems to be desactivated by   the start_url loops. I was not able to implement the solution you proposed and I didn't get the `for job in response.css('div.card-top')` part. I guess I'll just launch each query manualy, I don't have that much.

Comment: Look, just make a new question with full code of your spider (with all selectors and links) and I'll check your code. The issue with `start_urls` had been solved.

Comment: Ok, thx a lot I will do that. I'm now indeed noticing that there's something wrong in my spider...